# Does acquiring a spinlock require compare-and-swap or is swap enough?

Tags: concurrency, atomic, spinlock

Suppose we have a `spinlock` implementation:

```
struct Lock {
    locked : Atomic(bool),
}
```

Then an unlock function could be:

```
fun unlock(lock : &Lock) {
    atomic_store(&lock.locked, false, release);
}
```

But what about `lock`? Commonly, it uses a compare-and-swap like this:

```
fun lock(lock : &Lock) {
    while atomic_compare_and_swap(&lock.locked, false, true, acquire) {}
}
```

But wouldn't a swap be enough for this? Something like this:

```
fun lock(lock : &Lock) {
    while atomic_swap(&lock.locked, true, acquire) {}
}
```

Is there any problem with this?

Answer (score 4):

A compare-and-swap isn't really necessary. Atomically setting a flag `true` if it is `false` is logically equivalent to unconditionally setting it `true`.

An unconditional swap might be slightly faster since it does not have to compare anything, although the real cost of an atomic read-modify-write operation is in obtaining and locking the cache line.

Here is an example of a C++ spinlock that uses `exchange()`

```
#include <atomic>

class mutex {
    std::atomic<bool> flag{false};

public:
    void lock()
    {
        while (flag.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire));
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        flag.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
```