# C++ Can an atomic variable be declared inside a structure to protect those members?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, atomic

Have a structure declared and defined in  shared file.

Both threads create by the Windows API `CreateThread()` have visibility to the instance of it:

```
struct info
{
    std::atomic<bool> inUse; 
    string name;

};
info userStruct; //this guy shared between two threads
```

Thread 1 continually locking/unlocking to ***write*** to member in structure (same value for test):

```
    while (1)
    {
        userStruct.inUse = true;
        userStruct.name= "TEST";
        userStruct.inUse = false;
    }
```

Thread 2 ***just reading*** and printing, only if it happens to catch it unlocked

```
    while (1)
    {
        while (! userStruct.inUse.load() )
        {
            printf("** %d, %s\n\n", userStruct.inUse.load(), userStruct.name.c_str());
            Sleep(500); //slower reading
        }

        printf("In Use!\n");
    }
```

Expect to see a lot of:

> "In Use!"

and every once if it gets in, when unlocked:

> "0, TEST"

..and it does.

**But also seeing:**

> "**1**, TEST"

If the atomic bool is 1 I do NOT expect to ever see that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are performing 2 distict load on the atomic variable to check then output. the value can change between the loads

Comment: @tyker: ok I see, so would locking it again before the print and unlocing after the print be a correct way to use it? Thank You.

Comment: @P.S. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange is way to go. It compares and updates atomic variables atomically.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. Use the member method of atomic<>: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange

Comment: @quimby: could you please provide an example given this example above?

Comment: you nothing locking/unlocked here (unclear what you mean at all). the `name` and `inUse` independent. no any synchronization between threads. and for what atomic here ?

Comment: @P.S. Posted an answer, feel free to ask anything.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is not thread safe.  The atomic is atomic.  But the `if` statement isn't !

What happens:

```
Thread 1                                Thread 2               Comment 

while (! userStruct.inUse.load() )                             ---> InUse is false 
==> continues loop 
                                        inUse = true           
==> continues loop already started
printf(...)
```

In the worst case you could have UB due to a data race (one thread 2 modifies the string, and thread 1 reads the string during the modification).

#### Solution:

Since you intend to use your atomic as a lock, just use a real lock designed for this kind of synchronisation, using a [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) with a [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

For example:

```
struct info
{
    std::mutex access; 
    string name;
};
```

The first thread would then be:

```
while (1)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(userStruct.access); // protected until next iteration
    userStruct.name= "TEST";
}
```

The second thread could then attempt to gain access to mutex in a non-blocking fashion:

```
while (1)
{
    {  //  trying to lock the mutex
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(userStruct.access, std::try_to_lock);
        if(!lock.owns_lock()){   // if not successful do something else
            std::cout << "No lock" <<std::endl; 
        }
        else                     // if lock was successfull
        {
            std::cout << "Got access:" << userStruct.name <<std::endl;
        }
    } // at this stage, the lock is released.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/DQkaPG)

Comment: ahh, now I see it...but not sure if more locking in the other thread would be the correct way to use this?

Comment: @P.S. I think you are confusing atomic operation with locking, `atomic` from the STL only provides uninterrupted modification to a trivial type ( in your case a bool ) this does not make anything thread-safe. I think what you are looking for is a proper locking object which would be a [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) in the example you can see the usage along with `lock_gaurd`

Comment: @ChrisMc exactly lock_guard would be the solution for this use case.

Comment: @christophe: Thanks...few questions: In thread 1 the comment says "// protected until next iteration"...is that because it goes out of scope back in the while() statement and destroys the object? 

Is the member "userStruct.name" protected beucase how we are interpreting and specifically using the lock? or how does "lock(userStruct.access);" protect the other member? Thank you.

Comment: @P.S. Exactly!  The lock_guard locks the mutex.  At the end of the loop it goes out of scope, gets destroyed and therfore releases the mutex. THe protection is given by the mutex and the **convention** that you first aquire the mutex before using the other members (or any other resource or object in your code). The lock doesn't prevent against rogue access that is made without repect of the convention.

Answer (score 5):

you are performing 2 distict load on the atomic variable to check then output. the value can change between the loads. also you have a data race on your string variable.

you can fixe it easily by using std::atomic_flag or a mutex

```
struct info
{
    std::atomic_flag inUse;
    std::string name;

};

//writer
while (1)
{
    if (!userStruct.inUse.test_and_set()) {
        userStruct.name= "TEST";
        userStruct.inUse.clear();
    }
}

//reader
while (1)
{
    if (!userStruct.inUse.test_and_set())
    {
        printf("** %s\n\n", userStruct.name.c_str());
        userStruct.inUse.clear();
    }
    printf("In Use!\n");
}
```

you can't check the value in atomic_flag because it is almost always a bad idea to check the value of a lock because the value can change before you take your action.

Comment: I would probably use a `mutex` or even a `shared_mutex`, in the off chance that the code inside the protected section throws an exception. A mutex lock will unlock automatically when it goes out of scope. An `atomic_flag` does not clear automatically, you would need to make a custom RAII wrapper for that.

Comment: code is wrong anyway. the reader and writer can at once be inside `if` - first reader enter to if and set `inUse` to true, then writer enter to `if` to. code nothing synchronize and wrong

Comment: The `if` statement in the write needs to be inverted; you want to enter that block if the `inUse` flag is false

Comment: @LWimsey i fixed it

Comment: in this case yes, correct after fix. the code for enter critical region must be symmetric for both threads. also for highlight main concept - better use  `if (!userStruct.inUse.test_and_set(memory_order_acquire)) {
   ...
   userStruct.inUse.clear(memory_order_release);
  }`

Answer (score 2):

As Tyker pointed out in the comment, you have a race condition.( No need for inner while if its in infinite loop anyway.)

```
if (! userStruct.inUse.load() )
{
    //inUse might change in the middle printf
    printf("** %d, %s\n\n", userStruct.inUse.load(), userStruct.name.c_str());
    Sleep(500); //slower reading
}
else
   printf("In Use!\n");
```

Solution is to "lock" the reading, but simply doing the following is still not safe:

```
if (! userStruct.inUse.load() ) //#1
{
    //inUse might already be true here, so we didn't lock quickly enough. 
    userStruct.inUse=true; //#2
    printf("** %d, %s\n\n", userStruct.inUse.load(), userStruct.name.c_str());
    userStruct.inUse=false;
    Sleep(500); //slower reading
}
```

So, truly safe code is to fuse #1, #2 together:

```
bool f=false;
//Returns true if inUse==f and sets it to true
if(userStruct.inUse.compare_exchange_strong(f,true))
{
    printf("** %d, %s\n\n", userStruct.inUse.load(), userStruct.name.c_str());
    userStruct.inUse=false;
    Sleep(500); //slower reading
}
```

Comment: what sense of `userStruct.inUse.compare_exchange_strong(f,true)` ? you anyway got random value from `userStruct.inUse.load()` after this

Comment: Quimby, Although it's not wrong, technically you don't need a compare_exchange for a spinlock. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280739/does-acquiring-a-spinlock-require-compare-and-swap-or-is-swap-enough)